# Rails update multiple record with hash

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to update my data iteratively.

But the following way I achieved is the way too time-consuming.

Can I update multiple records with an `id-value` hash?

```
SUBST = ''.freeze
re = /<p>|<\/p>/m
(1..1000).each do |id|
  choice = QuestionChoice.find id
  choice.selections.gsub!(re, SUBST)
  choice.save! if choice.changed?
end
```

### Update:

Since I found out my code could be improved by using `where`

Like the following

```
QuestionChoice.where(id: (1..1000)).each do |choice|
  choice.selections.gsub!(re, SUBST)
  choice.save! if choice.changed?
end
```

But now I still need to call `save!` for every record which will cost much time.

Comment: Hi @Coda Chang, is there any callbacks when a choice is saved?

Comment: You could try batches - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

Comment: @fongfan999 is on the right track: do it all inside the database.

Comment: @fongfan999, yeah, it will return `true` if save successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting the db 1000 times sequentially to get each record separately, try to use single query to get all records you need to update:

```
SUBST = ''.freeze
re = /<p>|<\/p>/m
QuestionChoice.where('id <= 1000').map do |q| 
  q.selections.gsub!(re, SUBST) 
  q.save! if q.changed?
end
```

Comment: Oh, but in this way, the q still need to be `save` for 1000 times.

Comment: I've updated my question. the way is a good way to save `find` query, but I am looking for saving the `update` query.

Comment: @CodaChang if you are using `MySQL 8.0+` you can use `update_all` and make use of DB functionality `REGEXP_REPLACE` as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925597/5746504

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using MySQL 5.6, but it's also a good reference. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I used to face this problem and I solved it. Try to the following:

MySQL 8.0+:

```
QuestionChoice.where(id: 1..1000).update_all("selections = REGEXP_REPLACE(selections, '<p>|<\/p>', '')")
```

Others:

```
QuestionChoice.where(id: 1..1000).update_all("selections = REPLACE(selections, '</p>', '')")
```

or

```
QuestionChoice.where(id: 1..1000).update_all %{
  selections =
    CASE 
    WHEN selections RLIKE '<p>|<\/p>' 
    THEN REPLACE(selections,'<p>|<\/p>', '')
    END 
    WHERE selections RLIKE '<p>|<\/p>'
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: Try to put a few backlashes (`\`) to your regex pattern in the clause if needed.